# CVS log date format configuration

Tags: java, date-format, cvs, parseexception

I was working on CVS Log reader to do some validations on the formatting. After the CVS migration, I getting below error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011/05/30 08:27:24"
```

After investigation, i would that date format in the CVS log file has been changed from YYYY-MM-dd to YYYY/MM/dd. Due to which validation is failed.

Earlier format for CVS log is

```
RCS file: /opt/cvsrepositories/demo/Demo/source/demo_search/.classpath,v
Working file: source/demo_search/.classpath
head: 1.1
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 1; selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2014-07-14 09:50:57 +0000;  author: Dev.User;  state: Exp;  commitid: 62ee53c3a7d54567;
first version of the search module
=============================================================================
```

Now, it got changed to :

```
RCS file: /opt/cvsrepositories/demo/Demo/source/demo_search/.classpath,v
Working file: source/demo_search/.classpath
head: 1.1
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 1; selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2014/07/14 09:50:57 +0000;  author: Dev.User;  state: Exp;  commitid: 62ee53c3a7d54567;
first version of the search module
=============================================================================
```

I have checked for CVS manual, but there is no way to format the date format in logs.

Migrated machine is having same settings as per old machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating some more, i have found that problem was with CVS version. Migrated machine was having version as `1.11.x` But, earlier machine was having cvs version as `1.12.x`. After updating the version, Problem has been solved.

As latest version supports `date as in ISO8601 format`. 
There is a property `DateFormat=iso8601` in CVSROOT\config

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your reader, you need to use a parser like this:

```
 String strDate = "2011/05/30 08:27:24";
 SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/mm/dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = parserSDF.parse(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Yes, this could be done in java program to change the format or adding a fallback. My question is about, is there any configuration, which could be changed at CVS server level(config file), which defines the format of log file in `CVS log` command

Answer (score 0):

try to use this method in your code:

```
    private final static SimpleDateFormat OLD_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private final static SimpleDateFormat NEW_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static Date parseDate(String date){
           Date parsedDate;
           try {
               log.debug("Try to parse date using old format");
               parsedDate = OLD_FORMAT.parse(date);
               log.debug("Parsed date using old format");
          } catch (ParseException e) {
               log.debug("Failed while parsed date using old format");
               try {
                   log.debug("Try to parse date using new format");
                   parsedDate = NEW_FORMAT.parse(date);
                   log.debug("Parsed date using new format");
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Format of 'date' parameter must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
               }
          }
          return parsedDate;
     }
```

Comment: Yes, this could be done in java program to change the format or adding a fallback. My question is about, is there any configuration, which could be changed at CVS server level(config file), which defines the format of log file in `CVS log` command

Comment: What CVS  are you using?

Comment: I think, it is winCVS 1.11 version